# When will new Date() be run in my function?

Tags: node.js, date, functional-programming

I'm still fairly new to Node and Javascript and just want to check what's going on here but I'm not sure what to even look for.

I've created a couple of functions for comparing dates...

```
exports.isDateWithinRange = date => (from, to) => from <= date && date <= to;
exports.isCurrentDateInRange = isDateWithinRange(new Date());
```

These work (for now) but I just want to check.

In the second line... when is that `new Date()` calculated?

- Is it calculated every time the function `isCurrentDateInRange` called?
- Or is it calculated once when loading the file for the first time?

Because if it's the latter I need to change it. But I didn't want to bother changing it if it's not a problem.

Thanks

Comment: It's the latter. The closure resulting of calling `isDateWithinRange()` will be stored and used later on.

Comment: @Sirko ah, ok, thanks. I have updated it now to avoid that. I thought that might have been the case and yes... that makes complete sense now that you say it that way :D

Comment: `date` should be the rightmost parameter so that you can compose `isDateWithinRange` with other date expecting functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Date object is constructed whenever you require the module. And the isCurrentDateInRange will be the result of the immediate invocation of `isDateWithinRange`.

To avoid it you can use the exported `isDateWithinRange` and you can set default date value like this:

```
exports.isDateWithinRange = (date = new Date()) => (from, to) => from <= date && date <= to;
```

Comment: Thanks. With this are you suggesting to remove the `isCurrentDateInRange` function and just use the one function? Or keep it but make it like... `isCurrentDateInRange = this.isDateInRange()`?

Comment: You can remove the isDateWithinRang and use the exported function instead